# Отображения в разных окнах

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Сразу начну с того что заголовок темы неудачный (потому что не знаю как правильно выразится), ну ничего, постараюсь объяснить все что я хочу.
Допустим у меня есть форма (C#/wpf), в ней есть какой то Grid (с чем то важным), как мне вызвать этот же Grid в другой форме? Ну что то на подобии MessageBox, нажал на кнопку и появилось по центре окна. 
p.s. wpf/xaml знаю на низком уровне(пока), так что прошу(если конечно не трудно) написать маленький пример с объяснениями.
Спасибо за понимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас првильно понял, то вы хотите один раз описать какой то стиль для Grid'а и использовать его в разных местах. Для этого нужно создать ResourceDictionary или же описать свой UserControl. Я думаю для этого случая вполне хватит ResourceDictionary. Приведу пример:

Создаем ResourceDictionaty и называем его, например, **FirstResourceDictionary.xaml**. Далее в нем опишем наш Grid. Выглядеть **FirstResourceDictionary.xaml** будет примерно так:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyGrid">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Текст:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Далее в нужном нам окне где мы хотим использовать описанный нами Grid прописываем ресурсы:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="FirstResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Если же мы хотим использовать этот ResourceDictionary по всему приложение, не прописыввая его каждый раз в ресурсах окна, то прописать его нужно в App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Example.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="FirstResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Далее в контроле, где мы хотим отобразить этот Grid пишем следующее:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyGrid}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я сделал свой UserControl (не мог прочитать ваш ответ потому что интернет отключили, пришлось импровизировать).

Comment: Мне кажется, `UserControl` правильнее с точки зрения семантики.

Comment: Я думаю UserControl нужен, если необходимо функциональное наполнение, т.е., грубо говоря, строчки кода на C#/VB. Хотя могу ошибаться